# How to retrieve SmartContract details in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm working on a blockchain project and currently facing the interaction between front-end (react) and smartcontract. I need to retrieve my places that have been pushed on the blockchain to show them on the website:

The smart contract piece that I'm interested interacting to atm:

```
contract Prenotation {
    struct Place{
        string name;
        string description;
        bool isActive; //tells if the place is active
        uint256 price; //price per day in wei
        address owner; //owner of the place

        //keeps score if the place is booked on a particular day
        //example: isBooked[4] will denote that the place has been booked on th 3th of Jan
        //example 2: isBooked[31] -> the place is booked for the 1th of Feb
        bool[] isBooked;
    }
    
    //Sequential unique placeId for every new Place
    uint256 public placeId;
    
    mapping(uint256 => Place) public places;
    ...
```

That's how I tried to retrieve those Places (inside PrenotationContext.jsx):

```
const getEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const prenotationContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

    return prenotationContract;
}
export const PrenotationProvider = ({children}) => {
    ...
    const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
    ...
    const fetchAllPlaces = async () => {
        try {
            if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask");
            const prenotationContract = getEthereumContract();
            
            const placeId = await prenotationContract.methods.placeId().call()
            console.log(placeId)

            //return object containing places object
            const places = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < placeId; i++) {
                const place = await prenotationContract.methods.places(i).call();
                places.push({
                    id: i,
                    name: place.name,
                    description: place.description,
                    price: parseInt(place.price._hex) / (10 ** 18)
                })
            }
            setPlaces(places)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error("No ethereum object");
        }
    }
```

I fall into the catch with this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'placeId')
> at fetchAllPlaces (PrenotationContext.jsx:55:57)
> at checkIfWalletConnected (PrenotationContext.jsx:82:31)

I tried to verify if I correctly retrieve the contract and logging it on console after calling `getEthereumContract` I can successfully see it.

[Contract inside the web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApJmv.png)

In the checkIfWalletConnected I simply call the fetchAllPlaces method.
It's my first project working with solidity, react and all this so I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: As for now I solved the problem by creating a getter function into the Contract returning the placeId and rewriting `const placeId = await prenotationContract.methods.placeId().call()` as `const placeId = await prenotationContract.getPlaceId();` .
Same thing, for `const place = await prenotationContract.methods.places(i).call();` I've rewritten it as `const place = await prenotationContract.places(i);`

Answer (score 1):

In your current `for` implementation, if extracting fails in the middle of the operation, you are not going to get all places, you will get some of them. Instead

```
let places
try{
    // check if placeId is a string or number. I think Should be string
    const placeId = await prenotationContract.methods.placeId().call()

    places = await Promise.all(
         // since your for loop is till placeId
         Array(parseInt(placeId))
             .fill()
             .map((element, index) => {
                // since places is public, solidity assgins a getter automatically
                return prenotationContract.methods.places(index).call();
              })
           );
} catch (e) {
       console.log("error in extracting places", e);
    }
```